# How to subscribe when activated route selected in store

Tags: angular, ngxs

I am dispatching from one component and I listen for that in my other components. The problem is when I am in one component it is subscribing in other components.

I want to stop subscribe other components when I am in current component.

```
this.appStore.dispatch(new SetInformation({
              valid: true
            }));

  this.appStore.select<IInformation>(AppState.Information)
      .pipe(
        takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe),
    )
      .subscribe((Info) => { });
```

Answer (score 0):

import router module from angular router 
use router.url('selected route')